# rosbag2_py unable to import .so files that exist in lib

Tags: ros2

I am on a windows machine using a virtual machine through vscode and WSL to use ros2 (iron) so that I can write to rosbag2 files. When trying to import rosbag2_py, I get the Import Error:

```
    from rosbag2_py._reader import (
ImportError: librosbag2_compression.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even though librosbag2_compression.so does exist at `/opt/ros/iron/lib`

In the .py file, before I try to import rosbag2_py I append to the path by doing `sys.path.append('/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages')` because without it, the file isn't even able to find rosbag2_py to try and import it.

I also have `sys.path.append('/opt/ros/iron/lib/')` In an attempt to let python find the .so file, but this is not working.

I am very unfamiliar with ros and suspect that I am doing something wrong with the path, but I am not sure what exactly.